# What is a Grails "transactional" service?

Tags: grails, service, transactions, jta

I'm reading the Grails docs on [services](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/services.html) which make numerous mention of transactions/transactionality, but without really defining what a *transactional* service method really is.

> Given the nature of services, they frequently require transactional behaviour.

What exactly does this mean? Are *transactional* methods only those that use JPA/JDBC to communicate with a relational DB, or do they apply to anything covered by JTA?

Is there any reason why I just wouldn't make a service class `@Transactional` in case it evolves to some day use a transaction? In other words, are there performance concerns to making all service methods transactional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, if your performance concerns are due to the fact your services are transactional then you have reached nirvana. I say this because there are going to be plenty of other bottle necks in your application long before this is a major (or even minor) concern. So, don't fret about that.

Typically in Grails a `transaction` relates to the transactional state of a database connection or hibernate session. Though it could be anything managed by the JTA with the proper Spring configuration.

In simple terms, it's usually means (by default) a database transaction.

Answer (score 8):

Grails services are transactional by default - if you don't want a service to be transactional, you need to remove all `@Transactional` annotations (both Grails' `@grails.transaction.Transactional` and Spring's `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`) and add

```
static transactional = false
```

If you haven't disabled transactions with the `transactional` property and have no annotations, the service works the same as if it were annotated with Spring's annotation. That is, at runtime Spring creates a CGLIB proxy of your class and registers an instance of the proxy as the Spring bean, and it delegates to an instance of your actual class to do the database access and your business logic. This lets the proxy intercept all public method calls and start a new transaction, join an existing one, create a new one, etc.

The newer Grails annotation has all of the same settings as the Spring annotation, but it works a bit differently. Instead of triggering the creation of a single proxy, each method is rewritten by an AST transform during compilation, essentially creating a mini proxy for each method (this is obviously a simplification). This is better because the database access and transaction semantics are the same, but if you call one annotated method from another annotated with different settings, the different settings will be respected. But with a proxy, it's a direct call inside the delegate instance, and the proxy is bypassed. Since the proxy has all of the logic to create a new transaction or use other different settings, the two methods will use the first method's settings. With the Grails annotation every method works as expected.

There is a small performance hit involved for transactional methods, and this can accumulate if there are a lot of calls and/or a lot of traffic. Before your code runs, a transaction is started (assuming one isn't active) and to do this, a connection must be retrieved from the pool (DataSource) and configured to turn off autocommit, and make the various transaction settings (isolation, timeout, readonly, etc.) have to be made. But the Grails DataSource is actually a smart wrapper around the "real" one. It doesn't get a real JDBC Connection until you start a query, so all of the configuration settings are cached until then, and then "replayed" on the real connection. If the method doesn't do any database work (either because it never does, or because it exits early based on some condition before the db access code fires), then there's basically no database cost. But if it does, then things work as expected.

Don't rely on this DataSource proxying logic though - it's best to be explicit about which services are transactional and which aren't, and within each service which methods are transactional and which aren't. The best way to do this is by annotating methods as needed, or adding a single annotation at the class level if all methods use the same settings.

You can get more info in [this talk](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/grails-transaction-2gx) I did about transactions in Grails.